# It's right here. It's very very far

Tags: word, knowledge

> IT IS DIVINE
>
> IT’S A KILLER
>
> IT’S A GIFT
>
> IT’S A MEASURE
>
> IT’S A SOLID
>
> IT’S A LIQUID
>
> IT’S QUICK
>
> IT’S A CAR
>
> IT’S HERE IN A GLASS HOUSE
>
> IT’S VERY VERY FAR

What one word is it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it is:

> mercury

because:

> in the original order: god, poison, quicksilver, mmHg, solid, liquid, quicksilver, division of Ford, thermometer, planet

Comment: That sounds like a good answer, but would you mind writing it up a bit more tidily? It is usual here to answer such puzzles line by line, so that it is clear what each line means. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "solid"?

Comment: What I think on these questions proposed in some comments above and below: "quicksilver" can refer to the etymological part: it changes shape quickly. Besides, quicksilver can be used as a modifier to depict a person who is quick thinking, now, he is definitely quick, although here there was a jump from one homonym to  the other homonym, so it is interesting but dubious.  Besides, if you look at these: "it is quick", and "is a gift" notice that there is equivalency at first, and a reference at second just as inside the word quicksilver.

Comment: It is only the matter of circumstance whether mercury is liquid or solid hereby referring to the variable nature of it. Furthermore: it is possible that the emphasis is actually not put on the word "solid" here, but much more on "liquid",  referencing to the material itself in its most common form, while "solid" refers to the solids (constant shape or 3d) named after the material. Other things are also possible.

Comment: solid could refer to the planet's form,  as a  small rock, rather than a gas giant.

Answer (score 5):

IT IS DIVINE because

> Mercury was a Roman god.

IT’S A KILLER because

> the element Mercury is poisonous.

IT’S A GIFT because

> there is a gift card company called Mercury and Quicksilver.

IT’S A MEASURE because

> the element Mercury can be used in thermometers.

IT’S A SOLID because

> the element is solid below -37.89 degrees Fahrenheit

IT’S A LIQUID because

> the element is liquid above -37.89 degrees Fahrenheit

IT’S QUICK because

> the common name for the element Mercury is Quicksilver.

IT’S A CAR because

> Mercury is a make of cars and was a division of Ford.

IT’S HERE IN A GLASS HOUSE because

> Mercury is held in a glass tube for thermometers.

IT’S VERY VERY FAR because

> Mercury is a planet that is about 35.98 million miles away.

Comment: I wonder if the gift thing [is referring to this](https://genius.com/Zico-chain-mercury-gift-lyrics), but it's really obscure.

Comment: it is a measure is more likely to be: (rot13) zzut, juvpu vf hfrq nf n havg bs cerffher

Comment: Gift in German means poison

Answer (score 2):

It is

> Silver
>
> We gift silver . Silver kills vampires. It is measure in rank . It is solid .After melting it is liquid. We all know quick silver . And a silver car. I  think Glass house means Silver Jewellery for show in jewellery shops.

I missed two points .

Comment: "It is solid .After melting it is liquid." That's about the least specific fit to those words possible. Basically everything (there's a few exceptions like dry ice) melts from a solid to a liquid.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> Mercury.

IT IS DIVINE

> Mercury is the Roman god of war, also known as Hermes in Greek mythology.

IT’S A KILLER

> Mercury is extremely poisonous to humans.

IT’S A GIFT

> Does this refer to Mercury Gift cards? I'm not sure about this one...

IT’S A MEASURE

> mmHg stands for millimeter of mercury, which is a unit of measure used in the mathematics behind a mercury thermometer. An inch of mercury is also a unit of measure.

IT’S A SOLID

> The planet Mercury is a solid object.

IT’S A LIQUID

> The element is liquid at room temperature.

IT’S QUICK

> Another name for Mercury is quicksilver, due to its liquid nature at room temperature despite being a metal.

IT’S A CAR

> Lincoln Mercury is a type of car. (Well, now I don't think it's called that anymore, but it used to be.)

IT’S HERE IN A GLASS HOUSE

> Mercury used to be what was placed in the glass of a thermometer to measure the temperature. Not anymore though, due to its dangerous nature.

IT’S VERY VERY FAR

> The planet Mercury is very very far.

Comment: Do check the other answers before posting - this answer has already been given twice!

Comment: Is it against the rules to post a duplicate answer? I like to post my own guess before looking at other people's answers in case I get it wrong.

Comment: While it isn't 'against the rules' as such, it's recommended that you check existing answers first, then only post a separate answer if it hasn't already been done. You can always upvote other people's answers if you think they have it right, or comment on them if you think they *nearly* have it right and may have missed something. This community thrives both on new insights and on friendly collaboration. If everybody posted what they thought was the right answer and it already existed the site would be swamped in identical answers! By all means solve yourself first but only share if it's new!

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'll keep that in mind in the future.